How can I find minimal modulus of $z^2 - w z - 4$?
Let $z$ and $w$ be two complex numbers satisfying conditions:
$|z| = 2$ and $|w i - 2 + 5i| = 1.$ How can I find the minimum of $|z^2 - w z - 4|$?
I tried with setting $z = a + b i$ and $w = x + y i$:
Minimize[
 ComplexExpand /@ {Abs[(a + b  I)^2 - (x + I  y) (a + b  I) - 4 ], 
   Abs[a + b  I] == 2 && Abs[I  (x + I  y) - 2 + 5 I] == 1}, {x, y, 
  a, b}]

However, I can not get the result.


$|z|=2$ means $z=2e^{i\alpha}$
$|i w-2+5i|=1$ means $i w-2+5i=e^{i\beta}$

From these,
z = 2 E^(I*ɑ);
w = (E^(I*β) + 2 - 5 I)/I;

Abs[z^2 - w z - 4]^2 // ComplexExpand // FullSimplify
(*    -8 (-19 + 4 Cos[2ɑ] - 2 Cos[β] - 4 (2 + Cos[β]) Sin[ɑ] + 5 Sin[β])    *)

Minimize[%, {ɑ, β}, Reals]
(*    {64, {ɑ -> -293π/6, β -> -19π/2}}    *)

Concretely,
{z, w} /. {ɑ -> -293π/6, β -> -19π/2} // ComplexExpand
(*    {-I - Sqrt[3], -4 - 2 I}    *)

Geometric validation: there are two minima $z=-i\pm\sqrt{3}$ and $w=-4-2i$,
DensityPlot[Sqrt[-8 (-19 + 4 Cos[2ɑ] - 2 Cos[β] - 4 (2 + Cos[β]) Sin[ɑ] + 5 Sin[β])],
        {ɑ, 0, 2π}, {β, 0, 2π},
        MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, Mesh -> {{8.01}}, MeshStyle -> White,
        PlotPoints -> 100]



Reals in Minimize[%, {ɑ, β}, Reals] is superfluous.

Let us put z=2*Exp[I*t] and I*w - 2 +5*I = Exp[I*s]. The the task  can be written as
Minimize[{ComplexExpand[Abs[(2*Exp[I*t])^2 - (Exp[I*s] + 2 - 5*I)/I *2*
Exp[I*t] - 4]^2], t > -Pi && t <= Pi && s > -Pi && s <= Pi}, {s, t}]


{64, {s -> \[Pi]/2, t -> -((5 \[Pi])/6)}}

